# How to copy a file from root of SD Card to one of its parent directory

Tags: android, android-sdcard

Im having a file stored in the root of the SD card(i.e not inside any folder)..
but i need my file to be in data/local/ which is above the SD card..

my app is for root users..so i tried doing the following:

```
"cd "+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString()
mv file ../
```

It changes directory to SD Card but doesnt move the file..with error: failed on 'file' - Cross-device link, 255

So i cant move between different mediums .. im guessing so..
Help appreicated.. thanks!

Comment: Any would be fine..but id prefer move..

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`File.renameTo()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29) method in your code.

**Edit:**

Aha! **but** the documentation for this API says:

> On Android, applications are most likely to hit this restriction when
>   attempting to copy between internal storage and an SD card.

Hmmm...

I guess you'd have to copy the file and then delete the original.

Comment: i am not pasting to the SD Card .. but in a directory above it..
In SD Card file is at [HOME/ROOT]/mnt/sdcard/file and i need it in [HOME/ROOT]/data/local/file..

i tried using your answer like this:
`File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/file");
          f.renameTo(new File("data/local/file"));`
But that doesnt copy it..

Comment: Try copying the file and then deleting the original. Looks like that is the only solution across mount points.

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid so. Write code to copy the file & then delete the original. Edited the answer.

Comment: So you saying to copy the file using Java itself..or the using the linux cmd?

Comment: Either one would work. Which one you use depends on your need.

Comment: Thanks for answering..however with Java i couldn't move or copy it..i used the RootTools External Lib and since the mv cmd still gave me problems..i used the cp command..thanks anyways!